# Can i create a shared folder between ubuntu 13.10 and windows 8.1

Tags: shared-folders

I have a dual boot system with ubuntu 13.10 and windows 8.1. At times i can access windows file from ubuntu but not ubuntu files from windows. is there an option to create a shared folder so that i can put the common files in it and access from both ubuntu and windows when necessary

Answer (score 1):

The files on "ubuntu" are probably saved on an Ext4 partition, of which Windows does not support the reading or writing of.

Your first option is that you can use [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) to read the Ext4 partition on windows, but there is no support.

Your Second option is that any file on NTFS (which is what windows uses) should be fine on linux, as it has great NTFS support, so you should be able to just write to a folder on that partition.

If for some reason that doesn't work, you should be able to create a third partition formatted as FAT32 (bad) or NTFS, and just use this third partition as the cross over.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, in my opinion, is to use a NTFS/FAT32 partition. These partitions can be access in both Windows and Linux. You can do some changes to mount this partition at each boot time in Linux. And then you can use it to store files such a s music and videos that could be accessed easily in both the OS.